# Proving approximation for TSP-metric

Tags: algorithm, heuristics, traveling-salesman, approximation, np-hard

I got stuck with the following question:

Consider the following heuristic: Start with a tour containing only one vertex. At each step, find the vertex outside the tour with the lesser distance to some vertex of the tour. Let v be the outter vertex and u be the inner vertex. Add v right after u in the tour. Suppose that your edges follow the triangle distance property. How can we show that this heuristic is a 2-approximation for the TSP-metric problem?

Does anyone know how to start that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I really can't see why someone would vote this down...

Comment: Hint: What mathematical proof technique fits a situation where you have a state that you can assume has some property, and you incrementally modify this state somehow, and want to show that the resulting state continues to have this property?

Comment: (I'm not certain that this technique will work here, but it's the obvious one to try first.  And I don't think you should have been downvoted, but it's currently fashionable at SO to interpret the rules as narrowly as possible, and help with a proof is more more mathematics/CS than programming in some people's minds.  You could also try your question at the CS SE website.)

Comment: Hi @j_random_hacker, I understand you're suggesting to prove it by induction. If I have the algorithm working for `n-1` vertex, when I add a new one, I think I don't have too much control of how the previous tour will rearrange itself to include the nth vertex...

Comment: Right, I really don't understand why there's people who just downvote the question and give no reason to it. I mean, there's a chance of other people lose the interest in seeing a downvoted question an the main goal of the website, which is to spread knowledge gets lost. But anyway, thanks for the advice, I posted it in the Mathematics as well.

Comment: There is some (unknown to us) *optimal* solution for n vertices, and in that solution, including vertex n adds some distance x (i.e. deleting vertex n would reduce the total tour distance by x to some smaller value y).  We know that x >= 0 because otherwise the edge lengths would violate the Triangle Inequality.  See if you can relate x and y to the penalty incurred by adding vertex n to the heuristic solution for n-1 vertices.

Comment: Why do you believe that the proposed algorithm yields a 2-approximation? Is this homework?

Comment: "I posted it [\[on\] Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835602/2-approximation-for-tsp-metric) as well" - [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it is impossible to prove, the described algorithm is *not* a 2-approximation. The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) mentions the publication

Rosenkrantz, Daniel J.; Stearns, Richard E.; Lewis, Philip M., II (1977), "An Analysis of Several Heuristics for the Traveling Salesman Problem", SIAM Journal on Computing 6 (5): 563–581, doi:10.1137/0206041

in which apparently the authors show that the Nearest Neighbor heuristic yields an approximation ratio of `Theta( log n )`, where `n` is the number of locations, even if the instance satisfies the triangle inequality:

> Rosenkrantz et al. [1977] showed that the NN algorithm has the
>   approximation factor Theta(log|V|) for instances satisfying the
>   triangle inequality.

However, the OP might have described a different algorithm; an analysis of the approximation ratio of different greedy heuristics might be found in the followin article.

> SIAM Journal on Computing, 1977, Vol. 6, No. 3 : pp. 563-581 An
>   Analysis of Several Heuristics for the Traveling Salesman Problem
>   Rosenkrantz, D., Stearns, R., and Lewis, II, P. (doi: 10.1137/0206041)

Comment: Hi @Codor - thanks for the help. Indeed, this is homework, but I'm starting to think that it's misspecified. Also, I think it's a bit different from the NN algorithm, since the latter includes the closest vertex always at the end of the cycle, not between other two, as far as I know

Comment: @user137227 Thanks for the clarification so far. If you obtain a definite greedy algorithm with approximation ratio 2, please post an answer to this question; I would be keen to hear about it.

Comment: @user137227 Please see my updated answer; perhaps the algorithm is analyzed in the included reference - however I have no access to the article.